# Promise or Callback, which one is better to use with NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, promise, callback

I found that there are 2 different ways to write node functions using `promise` or `callback`, the first way is like following defining the `findByEmail` function:

```
class Users{
  static async findByEmail(email: any ) : Promise<Users | undefined>{
    const user: any = await Pools.execute(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?",
      [email])
      .then(rows => { 
        return rows[0];
       })
      .catch(err => console.log(err) );
      return user;
  };
}

router.post(
  "/api/users/signin",
  async (req: Request, res: Response , next: NextFunction) => {
     const { email, password } = req.body;
     const existingUser = await Users.findByEmail(email);
});
```

And the second way would be like:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Response {
      user?: Users;
    }
  }
}

  static async findByEmail(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const user = await Pools.execute(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?",
      [req.body.email])
      .then(rows => { 
         res.user = rows[0];
       })
      .catch(err => console.log(err) );
  };




router.post(
  "/api/users/signin",
  async (req: Request, res: Response , next: NextFunction) => {
    await Users.findByEmail(req, res);
    const existingUser = res.user;
});
```

I am not sure if this is a "opinion based" question or not? However my purpose of asking this is to know which way is a better practice and why? According to performance and other possible issues?

***In particular I like to know either it is better to write functions with the `return` value or using `response` object to add the returning value to that inside the `then()` function, like `.then(res.user = user)` instead of `const user = await pool.execute(SELECT ...)` ?***

Comment: For anything other than a single asynchronous operation, promises are clearly simpler to program, code good error handling for and implement branching logic.  This is why promises (particularly with  `await` were invented and then implemented in Javascript.

Comment: FYI, in the code examples you show in your question, it is usually best not to mix `await` and `.then()`.  Pick one coding style OR the other for a given function.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks for the comment. In general I like to know is it better writing functions with the return value or using response object to add the returning value to them inside the then() function, like .then(res.user = user) instead of const user = await pool.execute(SELECT ...) ?

Comment: Note that your `findByEmail()` function is a bit of a weird implementation with promises because if you get a DB error, the returned promise is still resolved, not rejected.  And, the caller does no error checking.  I would never recommend writing code this way.  If there's a DB error, that error or some other error should be propagated back to the caller as a rejection.

Comment: @jfriend00: How should I catch the DB errors? Because I thought if the `then()` function of a promise get executed it means the promise is resolved with no errors. I mean the DB response has had been OK.

Could you pleas rewrite the function as the best of your knowledge and experience?

Comment: I was trying to show you a better way to do this, but don't understand the intent here. 
 In your second `findByEmail()` why are you assigning to `res.user` and not returning any value as the resolved value?  That appears to be programming-by-side-effect rather than just creating a utility function that returns the desired value and let the caller do with that returned/resolved value as they want.

Comment: @jfriend00: Is the first code example OK or there is also flaws with that as well?

Comment: No, it has problems too.  You aren't propagating all errors back to the caller, aren't validating incoming parameters from the request, are inconsistently logging errors, aren't returning an error status when there is an error, etc...

Comment: Keep in mind that `.catch(err => console.log(err))` eats the error.  It turns the promise into a resolved promise with an `undefined` resolved value.  The caller never sees the error.  If you're going to log and propagate the error, you have to then `throw err` after logging to keep the promise rejected.  In my  suggested solution, I don't log the error at the lower level, I just let it propagate back up and thus don't have to face this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to impalement that makes the following improvements:

1. Makes `findByEmail()` into a utility function that is independent of the `req` and `res` objects and thus can be used generally.
2. Properly propagates all errors from `findByEmail()` back to the caller.
3. Implements some validation checks on incoming email field and makes separate error path for that.
4. Log all errors on the server
5. Check for all error conditions from the database request
6. Not mixing `.then()` and `await`.

Here's the code:

```
// resolves to null if email not found
// rejects if there's a database error
static async findByEmail(email) {
    const rows = await Pools.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [email]);
    if (!rows || !rows.length || !rows[0]) {
        return null;
    }
    return rows[0];
};

router.post("/api/users/signin", async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        // validate incoming parameters
        if (!req.body.email) {
            let errMsg = "No email value present in incoming signin request";
            console.log(errMsg);
            res.status(400).send(errMsg);
            return;
        }
        let user = await Users.findByEmail(req.body.email);
        if (!user) {
            // do whatever you would do if user tries to signin with non-existent email
            // presumably return something like a 404 status
        } else {
            // do whatever you wanted to do here with the user object after login
        }
    } catch(e) {
        // some sort of server error here, probably a database error, not the client's fault
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. But It seems you removed all the `then()` functions. I was thinking using `then()` is a modern preferred way of writing asyncronous functions in NodeJS and were trying to use `then()` function as much as I can. I am no a little confused about using `then()`. I don't know where should I use them?

Comment: @best_of_man - If you're using `await`, do not use `.then()` or `.catch()`.  `await` is a replacement for `.then()` and `try/catch` around an `await` is a replacement for `.catch()` (and will also catch other errors).

Comment: Your solution works, but I am still wondering to know how it works when you haven't define return value for the `findByEmail()` function? I mean something like `static async findByEmail(email) : Promise<User>{`

Comment: @best_of_man - I'm not a TypeScript guy, so you will have to fill in that TypeScript return value part.